# Where is the Cinderella Function?

Tags: haskell

I just wrote a small function because I couldn't find it on Hackage, but I am pretty sure that it has to be there and I just can't find it. Does someone know if it exists somewhere?

I present to you:

```
cinderella :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
cinderella f = foldr (\x (a,b) -> if f x then (x:a,b) else (a,x:b)) ([],[])
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
filterFilter f l = (filter f l, filter (not . f) l)
```

... but probably doesn't do two traversals.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(a+-%3E+Bool)+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+(%5Ba%5D%2C+%5Ba%5D) `partition` function?

Comment: `break` only splits at the longest matching prefix.

Comment: @Florian There are 3 items, check all of them (hint partition is 3rd)

Answer (score 11):

You want the [partition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3apartition) function.

Comment: Darn it you're too fast. +1 though

Comment: Ah ok ... that was too easy ... I implemented it using `Foldable` and haven't checked in `Data.List` ...